# Get Probability of a Classifier Output

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

If I have a file that contain the classification output(this classification output has been done in another program, no scikit-learn), I would like to get the output classification Probability(0-1) for the Classification output samples that I have on a csv file.

Thanks,

Comment: you have 0s or 1s in a file and want probability? is that all that you have?

Comment: That looks like a question for [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/), rather than here. But I think you need to rephrase it and give more detail.

Comment: If you do not have access to the other program I don't see any way to get the probabilities except reverse engineering (i.e. training the same classifier yourself, with the output of the other program as training data. The resulting probabilities will be most certainly wrong, but give you a rough estimate).

Comment: If it is not `scikit-learn` you use for classification, why is this tagged with `scikit-learn`?